# how to avoid calling page_load method when binding grid with different data

Tags: jqgrid, postback

i want to change the data in the gridview on a button click by binding it with a different List<> object on server side, It binds the data successfully but since its a post back on button click the grid view gets loaded with the old data which was initialized to it in the page_load method.

how can i avoid calling the page load method after binding the grid with fresh data in the onclick event of my button.

i tried using (!isPostBack) but it dose not help.

Comment: Did you figure out your problem? If my answer helped please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your button event set a grid parameter that posts back to your server control that indicates that you are changing which datasource feeds the grid, then reload the grid. It should only be now showing the new dataset.

Example:

$('#gridName').jqGrid('setGridParam', { postData: { ChangeGridDataSet: true} }).trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: 1}]);

Comment: thanks..
but i tried doing something like this and its working for now.
i assigned Session["grdData"] with the object i want to bind the grid in the button click event
and on page load if Session["grdData"] is null i load from the original object else i load from the session.
Will there be any side effects with this?

Comment: Probably not other then the normal stuff that goes along with dealing with Session objects.  I started out my project via session objects but I personally feel that having the grid be responsible for informing the controller of something like this is far superior.  No worrying about session time outs, application pooling, distributed hosting, etc.  All of those issues are null by simply adding in an extra parameter that is posted to the controller when the grid fetches data.